# pd.Timestamp is assimilated to dtype('O')?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, timestamp

I developed a simple function which returns an empty dataframe with correct column names and dtypes from a dictionary:

```py
import pandas as pd

def return_empty_dataframe(schema: dict[str, np.dtype]): 
    return pd.DataFrame(columns=schema.keys()).astype(schema)
```

which is used like that:

```py
import numpy as np 

schema = {'time': np.datetime64, 'power': float, 'profile': str}  
empty_df = return_empty_dataframe(schema)
```

I wanted to add the possibility to define a column to be of type `pd.Timestamp`. As pandas does not understand its own type and requires a timestamp column to be of type `np.datetime64`, I added the next code snippet to my function (to convert pd.Timestamp to np.datetime64 in the schema used to build the dataframe):

```py
def return_empty_dataframe(schema: dict[str, np.dtype]): 
    dict_col_types_no_timestamp = {key: val for key, val in schema.items() if val != pd.Timestamp} 
    dict_col_types_just_timestamp = {key: np.datetime64 for key, val in schema.items() if val == pd.Timestamp} 
    dict_col_types = dict_col_types_no_timestamp | dict_col_types_just_timestamp

    return pd.DataFrame(columns=dict_col_types.keys()).astype(dict_col_types)
```

and so far so good, I can define my columns to be of type pd.Timestamp

```py
schema = {'time': pd.Timestamp, 'power': float, 'profile': str}  
empty_df = return_empty_dataframe(schema)  # works
```

However, I have a problem when I use this function with some automatic column type detection, as it seems columns of dtype `object` (`dtype('O')`) are interpreted as pd.Timestamp.

To check that:

```py
pd.Timestamp == np.dtype('O')  # usually I have dtype('O') for string, or mixed types
> True
```

Is that a regular behaviour ?

It is a problem for me, as for instance

```py
schema = {'string_data': np.dtype(0), 'power': float, 'profile': str}  
empty_df = return_empty_dataframe(schema)  # works
```

and the column `string_data` is turned into a `np.datetime64` column.

Comment: Yes, I think so, almost every class is subclass of the Object class. `pd.DataFrame == np.dtype('O')` also is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally what you are experiencing is a big issue with numpy dtypes which pandas had to deal with for a long time. Basically everything that isn't a number is an object.

With pandas 2.0 there is now support for different datatypes namely provided by [Pyarrow](https://datapythonista.me/blog/pandas-20-and-the-arrow-revolution-part-i). So you can now be much more explicit with the datatypes since there are [more available](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/pyarrow.html) to you.

With pyarrow this works without any problems:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa

def return_empty_dataframe(schema: dict[str, np.dtype]): 
    return pd.DataFrame(columns=schema.keys()).astype(schema)

schema = {'time': 'time64[us][pyarrow]', 'power': 'float32[pyarrow]', 'profile': 'string[pyarrow]'}  
empty_df = return_empty_dataframe(schema)
```

I don't know if this will solve your problems, and this pyarrow backend is still early in development but it's something to keep in mind that this will give you better access to specific datatypes.